# How to run mysql query inside a WordPress post with shortcode without sending it to the footer

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, wordpress

I have a mysql code which works perfectly. I have gone ahead to create a custom shortcode for it so that I can embed the contents inside a post. I am having problems with the shortcode executing below the footer. I initially thought it's a plugin/theme issue but it's clearly not. Seems there is something with the code that makes it go below the footer. I think so because I added some text and images in the post content and everything runs properly. Here's the code that generates the shortcode `[todayrecords]`

```
<?php
function today_records_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?> <table border="1">
<th colspan="5" style="text-align:center;"> <h2 class="tomorrow">TODAY RECORDS </h2> </th>
<tr>
<th>Day</th>
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>Exam Type</th>
 <th>Student Name</th>
</tr>
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( 
"SELECT * FROM wp_mytyt
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM wp_myyg
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY date, examtype ASC;" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    ?>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo $print->day;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->date;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->examtype;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->sudentname;?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php }
  ?>    


 <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}


add_shortcode('todayrecords', 'today_records_shortcode');
```

Why is this code output going below the footer?

Comment: You don't close the table `</table>`

Comment: How did I even miss that? Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
function today_records_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
    // Your html code or output.
    <?php
    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $var;
}

add_shortcode('todayrecords', 'today_records_shortcode');
```